# Feature detection - Lion scrollbar

Tags: javascript

I have some css code that mimics Lion/iOS style scrollbars (like Twitter website). However, I would like to prevent the styles to be used for browsers that supports new scrollbars and are running Lion. Is there a better way than checking the user agent for WebKit+Lion ?

Comment: How does not having a visible scroll bar all the time (which is seen now in Lion) break your existing styles? Is there a particular reason not to have the styles run in Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly that in my plugin LionBars. The thing is, when there are normal scrollbars like say in windows xp, the div becomes 15px (or so) smaller in width. Where in OSX Lion, even with a scrollbar it remains the same width.

What I did in my script was I inserted a dummy display:block div in the div that I want to check for scrollbars and if the dummy div gets 15px shorter, then the user isn't running OSX. Have a look at my plugin, I believe I left good enough comments in the JS code:

[Link to my plugin](http://www.nikolaydyankov.com/lionbars)

Comment: Dude, what happened to your Lionbars plugin? I can't find it anywhere.